# Append divs changing his content dynamic

Tags: forms, html, dynamic, input, append

I have a dif called cdefualt that has some inputs from a form inside of it and I want to do something like this to clone it and change that input names:

```
var i = 2;
function add() {
    var item = $('#cdefault').clone();
    item.attr({'style': ''});
    $xpto = 'gtitle'+i;
    $xpto2 = 'gmessage'+i;
    item.id = $xpto;
    $('#'+$xpto+' input[id="gtitle1"]').attr('name', $xpto);
    $('#'+$xpto+' textarea[id="gmessage1"]').attr('name',$xpto2);
    $(item).appendTo('#ccontainer');
    i++;
}
```

But this doesnt work. I've tried this already as well but it only works twice (for the original and first clone):

```
var i = 2;
function add() {
    var item = $('#cdefault').clone();
    item.attr({'style': ''});
    $xpto = 'gtitle'+i;
    $xpto2 = 'gmessage'+i;
    $('#cdefault input[id="gtitle1"]').attr('id', $xpto);
    $('#cdefault textarea[id="gmessage1"]').attr('id',$xpto2);
    $('#cdefault input[name="gtitle1"]').attr('name', $xpto);
       $('#cdefault textarea[name="gmessage1"]').attr('name', $xpto2);
    $(item).appendTo('#ccontainer');
    i++;
}
```

Even tryed this way:

```
function add() {
    $xpto = 'gtitle'+i;
$xpto2 = 'gmessage'+i;
    var div = document.getElementById('cdefault');
    clone = div.cloneNode(true); // true means clone all childNodes and all event handlers
    clone.id = $xpto;
    clone.style.display = '';
    $("#"+$xpto+" input[id='gtitle1']").attr('name', $xpto);
    $("#"+$xpto+" textarea[id='gmessage1']").attr('name',$xpto2);
    document.getElementById('ccontainer').appendChild(clone);

    i++;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Theopt/xNfSd/

Comment: A fiddle would help to understand this.

Comment: done but its too much code i tried to paste something there so ppl get the ideia. I have a hidden div that I want to clone but change the form names somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed. changed cdefault id to id0 and this java script:

```
var i = 2;
var c = 0;
function add() {
    $xpto = 'gtitle'+i;
    $xpto2 = 'gmessage'+i;
    var klon = $( '#id'+ c );
    klon.clone().attr('id', 'id'+(++c) ).insertAfter( '#inserthere' );
    document.getElementById('id'+(c)).style.display = '' ;
    $("#id"+(c)+" input[id='gtitle1']").attr('name', $xpto);
    $("#id"+(c)+" textarea[id='gmessage1']").attr('name',$xpto2);
    i++;
}
```